How to return an implementation of a genericized subclass in Java
I have the following structure:
    class Base{}
    class Extension1 extends Base{}
    class Extension2 extends Base{}
    abstract class AbstractClazz<T extends Base>{}
    class Clazz1 extends AbstractClazz<Extension1>{}
    class Clazz2 extends AbstractClazz<Extension2>{}

    <T extends Base>  AbstractClazz<T> method(boolean returnClass1){
        if (returnClass1){
          return new Clazz1();
        }
        return new Class2();
    }

However, my compiler gives me an error stating "Cannot convert from Clazz1 to AbstractClazz".  I'm not sure why this is happening. Clazz1 and Clazz2 meet the requirements of an instance of AbstractClazz<T extends Base>, as far as I understand, because Clazz1 and Clazz2 are implementations of AbstractClazz where the the generic type is a subclass of Base, which is what AbstractClazz<T extends Base> is expecting.
How do I fix this?
note: my code is written using Java 8.

Clazz1 and 2 are AbstractClazz<Extension>, but method says it can return a AbstractClazz for any class that extends Base. It does not fulfil that contract. T might be Extension2 extends Base.

You can change method to return AbstractClazz<Extension> or AbstractClazz<? extends Base> and remove the generic param.

@Michael thanks for the reply. I've updated my example to more accurately reflect the problem I'm having.  Clazz1 and Clazz2, in my actual code, do not both use Extension

Most of what I said still applies, but now AbstractClazz<? extends Base> is the only possibility.

Maybe abstract factory pattern is appropriate?

<T extends Base>  AbstractClazz<T> method(boolean returnClass1){

Type parameters like <T extends Base> are in many ways like boolean returnClass1: the caller picks them.
For example, the caller can write
class MyRandomExtensionOfBase extends Base{}

AbstractClazz<MyRandomExtensionOfBase> thingy = Foo.<MyRandomExtensionOfBase>method(true);

...and that's supposed to work.
That's not what you have.  You have a function that returns AbstractClazz<? extends Base>, returning some AbstractClazz<T> for some T extends Base decided by the implementation of method.
You must return that type for this to typecheck.
